# pandas query returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, object, filter, dtype

When i use query to filter the itemsets(dtype: object) get an empty result.

My dataset:

| support | itemsets | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.049995 | (0) | 1 |
| 0.050006 | (1) | 1 |
| ........ | ........ |  |
| 0.049995 | (400, 140) | 2 |
| 0.050006 | (539, 559) | 2 |

Name: itemsets, Length: 569, dtype: object

My query:

```
print(support_values[(support_values.itemsets==(0))])
```

I try:

```
print(support_values[(support_values.itemsets=='(0)')])
print(support_values[(support_values.itemsets==0)])
print(support_values[(support_values.itemsets=='0')])
```

---

Result:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [support, itemsets, length]
Index: []

Comment: It is best if you provide your input data frame constructor code, this way we can see the exact structure of your dataframe.

Comment: Try this: `print(support_values[(support_values.itemsets=='(0)')])`

Comment: Since those are strings, you might have a problem with white space in your columns.
`support_values['itemsets'] = support_values['itemsets'].str.strip()` then run `print(support_values[support_values['itemsets'] == '(0)'])`

Comment: `support_values.itemsets.str.contains(r'\(0\)')`.